# Align paragraphs in the same line inside a table

Tags: html, css, alignment, lines, css-tables

I've been trying to make three paragraphs finish in the same line and I couldn't do it. Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxuzt/) for an example.

CSS Code for the paragraphs:

```
.taula3columnes td p
{
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```

I'd like to have the three paragraphs aligned so they finish in the same line. I've been trying with text-justify CSS property but I haven't been able.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement you need to use `column-count` property. Remove all the `td` and `p`. keep only one td and assign the css like below.

```
.taula3columnes td
{
text-align: justify;
text-justify: inter-word;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 8px;
width: auto;
-webkit-column-count:3;
-moz-column-count:3;
column-count:3;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxuzt/1/)

Comment: That worked, tho; the problem is that the three paragraphs are united and I'd like to have the three paragraphs separated in three columns where each paragraph would be in a column.

Comment: How you are expecting everything align equal with different content? If you want keep it to align bottom, top you will get empty space like how you are getting in bottom now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: inline-block;` which wil effectively sit the `p` tgas inline with each other. Though, couldn't you just input the text in to one paragraph?

```
.taula3columnes td p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work by setting that property. Well, I'm using a table because I want three columns for a website and I didn't find any better option. Much appreciated for your answer, anyway.